# How can I reinstall the AppCenter

Tags: release-loki, appcenter

Using

```
sudo apt-get install appcenter
```

in Terminal gives me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package appcenter is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'appcenter' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've encountered the same issue.
I deleted contain of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory by mistake.

Add a file into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` as named `appcenter.list`.

Insert the line below into the file that's been created newly:

`deb http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter xenial main`

then try again:

`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install appcenter`

I overcame the issue by this way.

Comment: Had to do this a few times but it finally kicked, thanks, working great now!

Comment: sudo apt-get install appcenter Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências... Pronto
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto E: Impossível encontrar o pacote appcenter its in portuguese language, I cant install it, why?

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt install --reinstall appcenter
```

Comment: 'Software-center is already the newest version'

Comment: yep, see the "about" section